# Is a Surjective Homomorphism Between a Finitely Generated Abelian Group and a Free Abelian Group Uniquely Determined?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've come across a statement that I do not understand.

In terms of notation here, we are letting $A$ be an abelian group generated by $n$ elements (let's say that these $n$ elements are in a set $S$) and letting $F$ be "the free abelian group on $n$ generators". I interpret the latter statement to mean that $F$ is generated by $S$, the set of generators for $A$, so the basis for $F$ is $S$, i.e., $F\approx\bigoplus\limits_{x\in{S}}\mathbb{Z}$

The statement is:

> By the universal property, there exists a surjective homomorphism$$F\xrightarrow{\varphi}A$$ of $F$ onto $A$.

In an attempt to parse this, I've proven that if $g\colon{S}\to{A}$ is any surjective mapping from the $n$-element generating set $S$ to $A$, then there exists a surjective homomorphism from $F$ to $A$. This is an easy application of the universal property.

But it is clear that there is no well-defined mapping from $S$ to $A$ that is surjective in this situation. So I'm lost on what I'm missing here. Any elucidation is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In general, there will be no surjective function $S\to A$, as $S$ may well have less elements than $A$!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Yes, I agree, but I was demonstrating that if there were some surjective mapping, then it would mean that there is a unique homomorphism from $F$ to $A$ that is surjective as well. The gist of my question isn't well stated, I suppose, but I'm trying to figure how the author of my text comes to the conclusion that there is a surjective homomorphism between the two groups in question.

Comment: Well, that is wrong. Usually, if there is *one* surjective homomorphism from $F$ to $A$, then there are *many*. This corresponds to the fact that in general there are many generating subsets in $A$ of cardinal $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably confusing a few things. Instead of trying to answer your question, which I honestly do not understand, let me explain what the author meant:

Let $S=\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ be a subset of $A$ which generates it, and let $F$ be a free abelian group with a basis $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ of $n$ elements. The universal property of $F$ implies at once that there is a unique homomorphism $f:F\to A$ such that $f(x_i)=a_i$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. That homomorphism is surjective: indeed, the image of $f$ is a subgroup of $A$ which contains the set $S$, which generates $A$.

Comment: In particular, there is no claim that there is only one surjective homomorphism $F\to A$; what is true, though, is that there is a unique surjective homomorphism $F\to A$ which maps each $x_i$ to the corresponding $a_i$, which is quite a different matter!

Comment: So it should be a surjection because, if we fix an element $a*\in A$, then there is a not necessarily unique $n$-tuple $(c_1,\ldots,c_n)$ of coefficients corresponding to each $a_i$ in a linear sum equalling $a*$, such that, by the definition of a homomorphism, $f(c_{1}x_1+\cdots+c_{n}x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{c_{i}a_i}$, demonstrating surjectivity? Moreover, shouldn't the image of $f$ be $A$ if $f$ is a surjection?

Comment: I guess you meant *surjetivity* instead of *injectivity*; the first sentence of your comment is ok. I don't understand what you mean in the 2nd sentence, though.

Comment: As I understand it, the image of the homomorphism $f$ is (in set-builder notation) $\text{Im}(f)=\{f(f')\colon f'\in{F}\}$, which, for $f$ a surjective function, happens to be all of $A$, its codomain?

Comment: actually yes, as soon as I wrote that comment, I realized what I had done was surjectivity, not injectivity haha...

Comment: Inded, that is the definition of surjectivity.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much!